# Asp.net Menu navigation active class property

Tags: c#, jquery, css, asp.net, javaquery

I put by navigation code in update panel using timer but after one minute the active menu disappears and show no active menu on the page but the selected page is still present....

let me share my code..

code for update panel counters
Aspx code:

```
        <asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" id="UpdatePanel1">
            <ContentTemplate>
            <asp:Timer runat="server" id="Timer1" Interval="10000" OnTick="Timer1_Tick"></asp:Timer>



            <nav class="navbar-default navbar-side" role="navigation" style="background-color: #333333; height:100%;">
        <div class="sidebar-collapse" style="background-color: #333333; height:100%;">
            <ul class="nav" id="main-menu">
            <li class="text-center">
                <img src="../assets/img/Logo.jpg" class="user-image img-responsive"/>                 </li>


<li>
                    <a  class="active-menu" id="MDB"  href="ManagerDashBoard.aspx"><i class="fa fa-dashboard fa-3x"></i>Manager DashBoard </a>                   
                </li>


                    <li>
                        <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-sitemap fa-3x"></i>Messages<span class="fa arrow"></span></a>
                        <ul class="nav nav-second-level">
                            <li>
                                <a id="MNMF" href="ManagerNewMessageForm.aspx">Create New Message</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a id="MI" href="ManagerInbox.aspx?Status=11">Inbox<span class="in-badge"><asp:Label ID="mgInLabel1" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label></span> </a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a id="MS" href="ManagerInbox.aspx?Status=22">Send<span ></span> </a>
                            </li>

                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                    <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-sitemap fa-3x"></i>Suggestion Follow Up<span class="fa arrow"></span></a>
                    <ul class="nav nav-second-level">

                         <li>
                            <a  id="MP" href="ManagerNewSuggestion.aspx?Status=7">Pending <span class="mr-badge"><asp:Label ID="SMRPLabel1" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label></span> </a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a id="MPP" href="ManagerNewSuggestion.aspx?Status=3">Postpone<span class="pp-badge"><asp:Label ID="PPLabel1" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label></span> </a>
                        </li>
                      <li>
                            <a id="MAR" href="ManagerNewSuggestion.aspx?Status=6">Archived<span class="ar-badge"><asp:Label ID="SARLabel4" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label></span></a>
                        </li>

                    </ul>
                  </li>  


                    <li>
                    <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-sitemap fa-3x"></i>Account Setting<span class="fa arrow"></span></a>
                    <ul class="nav nav-second-level">

                         <li>
                            <a id="MAC" href="ManagerAccount.aspx">Account Control</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a id="MUP" href="ManagerPassword.aspx">Update Password</a>
                        </li>

                    </ul>
                  </li>  


            </ul>

        </div>
         <div style="background-color: #333333; height: 400px;">

            </div>
    </nav>  


 </ContentTemplate>
```

C# Code :

```
public void msgcounter()
    {

        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["FBMNGTConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
        con.Open();

        int msgstatusid = 0;
        while (msgstatusid < 22)
        {

            string strquery2 = string.Empty;



            strquery2 = "select count(Status) as msgcntstatus  from  MessageApprovalTable where Status = " + msgstatusid + " and ToEmployee_ID =" + Session["Employee_Id"];





            SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand(strquery2, con);

            SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd2);
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();

            sda.Fill(ds);


            string mgcount = Convert.ToString(ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["msgcntstatus"]);


            switch (msgstatusid)
            {
                case 11:

                    mgInLabel1.Text = Convert.ToString(mgcount);

                    break;
                //case 22:
                //    mngsndLabel1.Text = Convert.ToString(mgcount);
                //    break;
                //case "2":
                //    strquery += " where Suggestion_Status = 2";
                //    break;

                default:
                    break;

            }





            msgstatusid++;
        }

    }



    protected void Timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        counter();
        msgcounter();
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kindly add below line to Timer_Tick,
Put ,Menu id : MDB ; Runat="Server"

**MDB.attributes.add("class","active-menu");**

for all pages You can take href value or Page name For Applying Active class on Menu item

Comment: where i will put this ?

Comment: assign id and runat="server" to Htmltag , and Write this Code to Code behind..                                                     
    MDB.attributes.add("class","active-menu");                                                                    where MDB is id of control